# OSGI: get reference to EJB from ServiceListener

Tags: osgi, glassfish-3, cdi, ejb-3.1

I use OSGI, Weld and Glassfish3.1

I have an OSGI module with ServiceListener. In ServiceListener I need to enter the registered services to my database. 
Initially I thought to write an EJB that goes to DB, and in ServiceListener add lookup/EJB injection that would bring EJB(The EJB and ServiceListener are in the same bundle).


However the lookup/EJB injection does not work:

```
    @EJB
private AdminService adminService;
```

```
     private class MyServiceListener implements ServiceListener {
            private AdminService adminService;

            public MyServiceListener(){
               adminService = (AdminService) ctx.lookup("java:global/com.war_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT/AdminService");
...
    }

        public synchronized void serviceChanged(ServiceEvent event) {
            switch (event.getType()) {
                case ServiceEvent.REGISTERED:
                    ServiceReference reference = event.getServiceReference();
                    adminService.installService(...);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I also tried to get EJB as OSGI service, with no success.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Maybe I shoudln't do it with ServiceListener?

thank you

UPD: I found kind of solution for this: add a startup singleton EJB that injects DAO service and adds a listener to OSGI, but it takes a bundleContext from static member from an activator. 
But it sometimes throws an IllegalStateException (bundleContext that is not active)

Comment: You should add the "glassfish" tag to this question. Integration between services and EJBs is a feature specific to Glassfish, so by tagging it appropriately you may attract the attention of somebody who knows about Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found kind of solution for this: add a startup singleton EJB that injects DAO service and adds a listener to OSGI.
But I'm still curious if there is a better approach

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `Export-EJB:ALL` in MENIFEST.MF, that will export all EJB as a service, then  you can use `@OSGiService` to get a service, for detail you can refer to ["OSGi Application Development using GlassFish Server"](http://glassfish.java.net/public/GF-OSGi-Features.pdf)

hope this can help you